# Javascript - case insensitive replace when the text you want to replace contains forward slashes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do a case insensitive replace based on a URL where I need to include forward slashes in the text to be replaced. I know that you can remove case sensitivity like this:

```
str.replace(/lorem/gi, 'ipsum');
```

But how would I do that if the text to replace contained a forward slash such as this:

```
str = 'http://example.com/lorem/ipsum.txt';
```

and I want to replace `/lorem/` with `/ipsum/`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to escape the forward slashes.  The character for that is the backslash \

```js
let str = 'http://example.com/lorem/ipsum.txt';
let final = str.replace(/\/lorem\//gi, '/ipsum/');

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: No need to escape `'\/ipsum\/'`  - that's exactly the same as `'/ipsum/'`

Comment: Exactly right, thanks.  I just copied his code and then escaped all the slashes without thinking about it.